# What is the name of small wooden debris waves bring to the sea from the coast?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have seen debris--not trash--that waves bring to the sea from the coast. These may include coast plants, e.g. small pieces of broken branches of trees, grass, bamboos, etc. These can travel miles away from the coast, floating on the surface. This is different from driftwood that waves bring back to the shore!

In the past, it was a sign let sailors know they were close to shore, just several miles away.

I tried to find a word that best describe this in English. Is there any word or phrase?

Comment: I think the common term is driftwood.

Comment: @Gus driftwood come back to the shore, because they are so big/heavy that incoming waves move them to the cost. But what I mean--to be more accurate--is very small pieces that gather around, merge together and float on the surface, when the sea is calm.

Comment: There's no special word for wood that does this. In general, _flotsam_ is a word for such material, but it's not limited to wood. _Jetsam_ is such material that has come from ships rather than from land. The pair of them -- _flotsam and jetsam_ -- form a fixed phrase.

Comment: Your description is confusing. Is it what's on the beach or what's is floating around on the ocean? Is it just wood or plant material, or is it anything that floats, like styrofoam or plastic too? You may have a singular concept in mind but there may not be a word just for that. 'Flotsam and jetsam' is the fixed phrase for any random debris, wood/plastic/seaweed/a mix usually floating on the water, out at sea or in a harbor or washed up on the beach. Driftwood is wood washed up on the beach (but I suppose also out in the ocean).

Comment: So many of the terms involved relate to man-made waste. I think you would have to be very specific to describe what you mean. 'Natural, floating, oceanic debris' might fit.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Some information will help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 12):

Ancient floatsam modern [flotsam](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/flotsam-jetsam.html)

Flotsam is defined as debris in the water that was not deliberately thrown overboard, traditionally as a result from a shipwreck or accident. As such it belongs to the former owner who can reclaim it.

We usually combine it with jetsam which is discarded rubbish, normally thrown overboard. Which becomes the property of the finder.

Collectively they are used for floating **"Marine debris"** which is defined as any persistent solid material that is manufactured or processed and directly or indirectly, intentionally or unintentionally, disposed of or abandoned into the marine environment or the Great Lakes. The Government of Japan estimated that the 2011 tsunami created 5 million tons of marine debris.

When found on the beach marine debris can be called [**tidewrack**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tidewrack).

So floating on the sea it is best described as simply [wrack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrack) which includes marine vegetable matter such as "Bladder Wrack" seaweed.

[Interesting asides] The method by which tree seeds and live animals are carried adrift from land mass to land mass is called "Oceanic dispersal" and can include large **rafts** of vegetation with living materials e.g. Lemurs to Madagascar. Different to freshwater flotant marshland a floating living island is called a ["floaton"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_island). A group of similar vegetation (plants or shrubs) is classified as a Free-floating Forb.

Comment: Unfortunately, the word I am looking for is not flotsam. Flotsam can be seen anywhere in the sea, for example as you said from a shipwreck, not necessarily from the land.

Comment: @Osh But flotsam _could_ be seen from land. Being able to see it from land doesn't make it not flotsam anymore. I think "flotsam and jetsam" is _exactly_ what you're looking for here.

Comment: @KJO I believe wrack is closer but not exactly what I am looking for. I tried to find a picture on Internet so better describe the fact, but unfortunately could not, because obviously had not the best keyword.

Comment: Does flotsam ever occur by itself?

Comment: @Osh you can look it up on Google images using the word in your native language...?

Comment: @Mitch I would expect it _usually_ does. Flotsam is, by definition, from a wreckage. Jetsam is, by definition, not. In a colloquial sense, however, flotsam means the same thing as jetsam. So it's kind of... weird.

Answer (score 7):

The word you're looking for is **driftwood**:

> Driftwood is wood that has been washed onto a shore or beach of a sea, lake, or river by the action of winds, tides or waves. It is a form of marine debris or tidewrack.
>
> In some waterfront areas, driftwood is a major nuisance. However, the driftwood provides shelter and food for birds, fish and other aquatic species as it floats in the ocean.
> <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driftwood)</sub>

Driftwood is used no matter the size or even if it's just floating in the ocean and hasn't washed up yet. If you need more clarification that it's not large driftwood, you can say something like "driftwood twigs" or "driftwood pieces".

See for example these pages:

- Etsy: [driftwood twigs/sticks](https://www.etsy.com/search?q=%22driftwood%22%20twigs), [driftwood pieces](https://www.etsy.com/search?q=driftwood%20pieces), [driftwood necklaces](https://www.etsy.com/market/driftwood_necklace)
- Alibaba: [driftwood chips](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/driftwood-chips-decor.html)

Answer (score 0):

detritus [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/detritus)

> 1. rock in small particles or **other material** worn or broken away from a mass, as by the action of water or glacial ice.
> 2. any **disintegrated material**; debris.

And from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/51341?redirectedFrom=detritus#eid)

> a. transf. and fig. Waste or disintegrated material of any kind;
>   debris.  b. An accumulation of debris of any sort.

**Flotsam**, i agree is a good answer!  Thus my answer as in generic detritus!  I have heard seashore/beach litter also used.

From one google book:  [Dearie: The Remarkable Life of Julia Child](https://books.google.com/books?id=AVIkpbIYrEsC&lpg=PA155&dq=%22seashore%20detritus%22&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q=%22seashore%20detritus%22&f=false)

> Rachel and Julia began making funny hats for each other out of
>   **seashore detritus**, such as seaweed and lobster claws.

Answer (score -1):

Other possible words which would describe would be: 
flotsam (debris after a shipwreck) or jetsam (debris thrown overboard from a ship)

Comment: Mark, welcome to EL&U. Understand that to be taken seriously as a contributor here you should expect to have to spell your responses correctly: it's *flotsam and jetsam*, not "Floatsam ... or Jetsam".

Comment: @KJO It's still important not to capitalize words that should not be capitalized.

Comment: @KJO: Archaic forms are still considered misspellings in a modern context.

Comment: @Robusto try telling that to cerberus who uses the letters œ and æ and tchrist! :) and his NYT diaeresis

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I've given up on Cerb ... he is alternately a special creature and the Doggy from Hell! ^_^